# Onblur event mistakenly fires in IE when parts of popup document are clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, popup, onblur

I have a bunch of small pop-up pages that are designed to self-close when they lose focus - i.e. the user clicks on the parent document.

Unfortunately in IE8, the blur also occurs when the user starts to fill out an input form inside the pop-up page.
Indeed clicking *anywhere* inside the form causes this, or even when the user accidentally clicks on some  text. It seems these items are not part of the pop-up document.

How can I make them so?

Here's my blur code (inside a .js script) that I use on the several pop-ups:

```
var fClose=0 

onload=function() {   
 fClose=0  
 setTimeout("doClose()",111);  
 document.onblur=Blur_Me;  
 document.onfocusout = Blur_Me;  
}  

function Blur_Me(){  
 fClose=1;  
 setTimeout("doClose()",111);  
}    
function doClose(){  
 if(fClose)close();  
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `.onblur` and `.onfocusout` document events? Have you tried using only one or the other?

Comment: Yes- I read somewhere that IE "preferred" onfocusout. An MS "standard?   Originally it was just onblur.  
But I'll try it again without the onfocusout...

Comment: I tried it without the onfocusout and now it will not close AT ALL in IE.   But it works fine in FF (Have'nt tried Chrome or Safari yet)

Comment: OK, guys- no response yet?   
You will note that I forgot a semicolon in the Fclose=0 statement above. It was corrected, but still made no difference.  

 I am gonna make a simple sample simon set of web-pages that you can display and see what what with various browsers,op systems (Win & Linux) and we shall get to the bottom of this blur / focus / onfocusout on child pop-up pages.   

 (and perhaps optionally css display:none divs in place of pop-ups)   

 I SHALL get this to work!  
 This comment may no longer be edited?  GRRRR!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `blur()` you can use jQuery's `focusin()` and `focusout()` handlers.

The `focusin` event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus.

The `focusout` event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus.

These are distinct from blur() in that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).